# Searching for n comma separated values in an excel range using SQL

Tags: sql, excel, ado, vba

I have a multi-select listbox in Excel and am trying to search for the selected values in the database column using SQL through ADO

For example, I have a multiselect listbox with the following values:

```
 1. Mango
 2. Apple
 3. Grapes
 4. Banana
```

Sample data:

```
  ID     | LOB
  ---------------------------    
  ACQ1   | Apple, Mango
  ACQ2   | Mango
  ACQ3   | Apple, Banana, Mango
  ACQ4   | Apple, Grapes, Mango
```

If I select Mango and Apple from the listbox, I want to search for all the rows having Mango and Apple in the `LOB` column.

The problem I am facing is that my selections can change and accordingly query has to be adjusted. Is there a way to automate the query so as to search for all the values selected in the listbox?

Note: selections made in listbox are being stored as a comma separated value

Following is the code that I am using for an exact match of listbox selections (Returns rows with only "Apple, Mango"), I need to make it work for any combination of listbox values (Should also return rows for "Apple, Banana, Mango" or any other combination with Mango and Apple present in the cell):

```
Public Sub conn()

Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String

DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

ls_values = Sheet("Data").Range("A1").Value

conn.Open sconnect
sSQLSting = "SELECT * From [Sheet1$] Where LOB = '" & ls_values & "'

mrs.Open sSQLSting, conn
Sheets("Main").Range("B4").CopyFromRecordset mrs
mrs.Close
conn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Would help to show your current code.  One approach is to build a SQL where clause something like `...where LOB like '%Mango%' or LOB like '%Apple%'`

Comment: Hey Tim, The problem is that the selections are not consistent. They might change from (Mango, Apple) to (Banana, Grapes) or any other listbox value combination for that matter, in which case your code wont be applicable. I want to search based on the values selected in the listbox
Current Code: #Not writing ADO connection codes due to char limit
'listbox selections are in cell A1 as a comma separated value
ls_values = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
sqlSting = "SELECT * From [Sheet1$] Where LOB = '" & ls_values & "'"
mrs.Open sqlSting, conn
Sheets("Main").Range("B4").CopyFromRecordset mrs

Comment: You can edit your question to add your code.  I wasn't suggesting you use a fixed SQL string: you would loop over the selected list items and build the where clause dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the similar problem. My excel sheet column contains the value "1,2,3" and I want to select rows having value "1".

```
Col1 (A): 1,2,3 [contains comma separated numeric values]

Col2 (B): value one,value two,value three [contains comma separated strings]
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] A WHERE A.Col2 LIKE '%value1%' AND (A.Col1 LIKE '2%' OR A.Col1 LIKE '%2%' OR A.Col1 LIKE '%2' OR A.Col1 LIKE '2')
```

> Rows returned: 0

Comma separated values work fine when excel column contains comma separated strings but fails when they contain numeric comma separated values
i.e. This query returns correct results:

```
SELECT *  FROM [Sheet1$] A WHERE A.Col2 LIKE '%value one%'
```

There is no issue in connection/rs objects and strings etc. I'm using the same function for all other queries which do not have queries on comma-separated numeric values

---

**Solved my problem**: It turned out to be a formatting issue... I had following values in

Col1 (A)

1
1
1
1,2,3
2,3
3,4,5

Excel Formatting was 'General' Because of 'General' formatting, excel picked up first 3 rows as numbers and next 3 as text... query failed to retrieve text and threw an error message as follows:
"you cannot record changes because a value you entered violates the settings defined for this table or list (for example, a value is less than the minimum or greater than the maximum)...

---